# How to add lines from text file to sqlite db rows that already exist?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 12 columns with +/- 2000 rows in a sqlite DB.

Now I want to add a 13th column with the same amount of rows.
If I import the text from a cvs file it will add this after the existing rows (now I have a 4000 row table)

How can I avoid adding it underneath these rows?

Do I need to create a script to run trough each row of the table and add the text from the cvs file for each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Razor SQL great program.

http://www.razorsql.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have the code that imported the original data, and if the data has not changed in the meantime, you could just drop the table and reimport it.

Otherwise, you indeed have to create a script that looks up the corresponding record in the table and updates it.

You could also import the new data into a temporary table, and then copy the values over with a command like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET NewColumn = (SELECT NewColumn
                 FROM TempTable
                 WHERE ID = MyTable.ID)
```